# How do I print the result of a variable in google apps script to the console?

Tags: google-apps-script, logging

I am currently running this code:

````
```
function getRandomValues() {
  var values = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    values.push([Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1)]);
  }
  return values;
   Logger.log(values);
}

```
````

Which I was hoping would pick a random number between 1 and 100, then print it to the console. For all I know the picking a number section is working perfectly well but I want to check it before continuing and I'm struggling to get an output anywhere that I can see.

I have tried a good amount of research on google to find other people experienceing the same issues which led me to using "Logger.log" but no matter what I do after that I don't get a value to the console. Even when I try just writing ("Hello World!") within the logger.log brackets it doesn't work. I have tried putting many things between the brackets such as (var values), (values []), (return values), (values result) and (values return) but nothing works. As I'm sure you can tell by now I am incredibly new to google apps script and I am within my first 3 hours of trying to learn it to create a simple project. I do see that my "Logger.log(values);" is greyed out in my script and have to assume that is one of the issues but I don't know how to fix that. The only thing I find online is people not declaring variables properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your script, `Logger.log(values);` is used after the line of `return values;`. Your function is finished at `return values;`. I think that if my understanding of your expected result is correct, this might be the reason for your current issue. So, if you want to see `values` in the log, please put `Logger.log(values);` just before the line of `return values;` and test it again. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize. By the way, can I ask you about the detail of `Even when I try just writing ("Hello World!") within the logger.log brackets it doesn't work.`?

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. It simply wasn't working at all because it was running after the function finishes. The detail was that even when I put things I definetly knew should work in the log function they still wouldn't.

Comment: How would I accomplish this? I can not find any flag to show the world your coding prowess.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I posted it as an answer by adding the explanation. Please confirm it. If there are several modification points, please tell me. By this, you can accept the answer as a resolved answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of your following script,

```js
function getRandomValues() {
  var values = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    values.push([Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1)]);
  }
  return values;
   Logger.log(values);
}
```

`Logger.log(values)` is put after `return values`. In the current stage, Google Apps Script is run with the synchronous process and your function finishes at `return values`. By this, the script is finished after `Logger.log(values)` is run. I thought that this is the reason for your current issue.

In order to show `values` in the log, please put `Logger.log(values)` before the line of `return values`. So, please modify it as follows.

```js
function getRandomValues() {
  var values = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    values.push([Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)]);
  }
  Logger.log(values); // <--- here
  return values;
}
```

By this modification, when you run the function `getRandomValues()`, you can see the values of `values` in the log.